# Package net.proteanit.sql is declared in module rs2xml, which is not in the module graph

Tags: java, java-module

I tried to import DbUtils in Java, but I get this error. This is message I get. How to resolve this? I tried many methods, but it's still not working. I added rs2xml jar to library as well.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9gEZ.png)

Package net.proteanit.sql is not visible

Package net.proteanit.sql is declared in module rs2xml, which is not in the module graph

Comment: You have a modular Java project and have not declared the rs2xml module in your `module-info.java`. Either add it, or if you don't want to use Java modules, remove the `module-info.java`.

Comment: I added and it worked. Thanks, Also had remove jar file from module and add jar to classpath.